# Unable to use web based functions in react native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, mobile-application, tensorflow.js

I am developing a native application in react native with expo. I am using typescript. I have existing tensorflow models and I am using tfjs browser methods to convert an image to tensor `tf.browser.fromPixels()`. This method accepts **HTMLImageElement** or **ImageData** as mentioned in the [documentation](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#browser.fromPixels).

I am trying to initialize a new image object and assign the base64 data string to the `src` attribute, that I get from my expo-camera `takePictureAsync()` response and then passing the image object to canvas using [node-canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas).

```
const img = new Image()
```

But using the constructor results into error as follows;

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Image
```

I do not receive any import error for using `Image` constructor. Is it not possible to use web view methods in react native? What am I doing wrong here?

---

I also tried **Image** from node-canvas but still getting an error.

```
import { Image } from "canvas"
```

and then when trying to initialize using the constructor and getting following error;

```
TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new _canvas.Image()')
```

What does the error mean?

Comment: React native is not a web browser. Many things that browsers provide are not available in a react native context. The `Image` class is one of those. Though, `ImageData` _may_ be available.

Comment: How do you import node-canvas?
If you don’t have to use node-canvas you can use react-native-skia (https://github.com/Shopify/react-native-skia)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @AlexWayne. I will try using ImageData.

Comment: @MichaelBahl I will try react-native-skia. Thanks for providing the link.

Answer (score 0):

you can just save it as a normal string, there is no need to create an object. when you will show the image with the saved base64 just do this:

```
import {Image} from 'react-native';

const photoBase64= data:undefined;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4gIoSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAIYAAAAAAIQAABtbnRyUkdCIFhZWiAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABhY3NwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAA9tYAAQAAAADTLQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAlkZXNjAAAA8AAAAHRyWFlaAAABZAAAABRnWFlaAAABeAAAABRiWFlaAAABjAAAABRyVFJDAAABoAAAAChnVFJDAAABoAAAAChiVFJDAAABoAAAACh3dHB0AAAByAAAABRjcHJ0AAAB3AAAADxtbHVjAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAMZW5VUwAAAFgAAAAcAHMAUgBHAEIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA;   

<Image
 source={{ uri: photoBase64 }}
 className="h-full w-full"
/>
```

Comment: the problem is not displaying the picture. I want to transform the image into tensor using tf.browser.fromPixel and it only accepts objects of Image or ImageData type as mentioned in my question.